# Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: spring-boot, soap-client

I have a spring boot 2.x application that is making a soap call using JaxWsProxyFactoryBean to make the calls.  All of the calls are working flawlessly except for one that is getting "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out".  Things to note:

- My application is having no problems with soap calls within my network.
- The only soap call having an issue is outside of my network and the issue is sporadic
- From network traces it also appears my application is reusing connections (connection pooling)
- My application makes millions of calls per day to both the internal (working soap serivces) and the external service that is having the blips

Questions:

- How do I configure http connection pooling in spring boot 2.0?
- Is it likely the issue will go away if I disable HTTP connection pooling?
- What type of performance hit (estimate in ms) am I looking at if I disable HTTP connection pooling?
- What could the causes of my issue be if its not related to the connection pool?

If you need any other details please let me know.

Partial Stack Trace:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:933)
 at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:735)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1587)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
 at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
 at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream$2.run(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:377)
 at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream$2.run(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:373)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.getResponseCode(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:373)
 at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.doProcessResponseCode(HTTPConduit.java:1597)  
 at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1625)
 at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1570) 
 at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1371)  ...
```

Thanks,
Brian